# Update or not a column, if select returns a record

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have two tables: `LABELS` table has two columns `oldLabel` and `label` and the other table `INVENTORY` has a column `label` which contains the values of the column `LABELS.oldLabel`.

I want to update the values of the column `INVENTORY.label` with the values of `LABELS.label`. I tried:

```
UPDATE INVENTORY
SET label = (SELECT label FROM LABELS AS T2 WHERE T2.oldLabel = INVENTORY.label);
```

which works but if the `SELECT` doesn't return a value, then the `INVENTORY.label` gets a null value. How can I alter the above query, so when the `SELECT` doesn't return a record, don't update that record!

I found a way which I use some `JAVA` implementation..

```
sq = "UPDATE INVENTORY "
        + "SET label = ? WHERE label = ?";
stm = c.prepareStatement(sq);

for (Label label : labels) { //labels is an arrayList which contains both values
    stm.setString(1, label.getLabel());
    stm.setString(2, label.getOldLabel());

    result = stm.executeUpdate();
}
```

However, can I do this with SQL code only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a WHERE clause to the UPDATE:

```
UPDATE INVENTORY
SET label = (SELECT ...)
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT ...);
```